Is holiday only a Commonwealth synonym for vacation, or does it also replace words like "trip" and "break" as well?
I am pretty sure holiday just means what Americans call a vacation as well as a long trip meant only for relaxation or even an extended period of time off from work or school.
I dont think people are going to say "business holiday" for "business trip", and for a day trip, it wont really make sense to call that a "day holiday". Not all trips can be holidays, while not all holidays are trips.
Then comes work breaks. No one is going to call a work break a "work holiday", cause work holiday means an extended time off from work, not just 10 minutes of paid time during your shift when you do not actually have to do work. Not all breaks are holidays, while all holidays can be seen as a break.
I think holiday in Britain and Australia just replace what Americans call a "vacation", and what they call "winter break", "spring break", and "Thanksgiving break". People there do sometimes call trips "vacations" in America, while in Britain and Australia, they call trips of relaxation "holidays".
Vacation sometimes replaces trip in America, and instead of summer break, people call it summer vacation there.

Holiday is simply a contraction of "Holy Day", so originally something done on a religious festival.  The US changed to Vacation to remove religious connorations.

Holiday doesn't 'replace' trip and break. A trip (for pleasure, and of more than a day or two) could also be a holiday. The time between school or university terms is sometimes called a break, but more often 'the holiday(s)', and universities formally call it 'the vacation'.

Maybe in US, but I doubt Britain and Australian universities formally call it a vacation.

A "holiday" can be used for both a day (or days) off work or school, or when you spend time away from home for pleasure, ie a vacation.
So a "business holiday" would be an oxymoron.
Holiday has a wider sense that vacation, since we can say that "Boxing day is a holiday", or "the half-term holiday at the end of May",  but these "holidays" are not vacations, though they might be "holidays" or "breaks" in the USA.
"Trip" is more about the journey, whereas a holiday is more about being away.  You might say that the holiday to Spain started with a trip on an aeroplane.
